# SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2014 ERRO (Microsoft SQL Server, erro 1225)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-express

Bom dia, tudo bem pessoal?

Seguinte trabalho com banco de dados, e estamos com alguns problemas com o SQL SERVER 2014 x64, no Windows 10. Estou fazendo a instalação normalmente e alterando a configuração de rede, no TCP/IP, para uma porta especifica que utilizamos.

Porém já fiz vários testes e continua me gerando sempre o mesmo erro, segue mensagem abaixo:

```
Erro de rede ou específico á instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL SERVER. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. 
Verifique se o nome da instância esta correto e se o SQL Server esta configurado para permitir conexões remotas. 
(provider: TCP Provider, error:0 . O computador remoto recusou a conexão de rede.) (Microsoft SQL Server, erro 1225)

O computador remoto recusou a conexão de rede.
```

Alguém pode me auxiliar?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: A tentativa de acesso esta sendo remota? Se sim. Foi dada permissão de acesso remoto ao banco?

Comment: Mesmo sendo local, faça o teste de desativar o firewall do windows.

Answer (score 1):

Veja esse [tutorial](http://www.systematiza.com.br/site/?page_id=837)

Creio que voce nao tenho configurado os protocolos para acesso remoto, que por padrao, estao desativados (segurança)

Att

Comment: boa tarde, então a conexão esta sendo feita localmente. E mesmo assim ele não deixa logar...

Comment: Tutorial muito bom! Bem explicado! Pena que não solucionou o problema do nosso colega.